# How do I get wheat seeds?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I get wheat seeds? (Not by village farms)
I used the hoe on grass blocks but seeds didn't drop.

Answer (score 1):

Seeds have a chance to drop by breaking Grass (not Grass Block). If you really can’t collect grass after a few tries, try to reinstall minecraft or make sure you don’t have any mods interfering it.

Yes, Mods in pocket edition do exist; try to save your world by connecting your phone (if android) and move the world file.

Comment: Tall grass has to be broken to get seeds.

Comment: Just tried to break small grass, still got seeds. Try re-installing it. Might work.