# How to get wheat seeds in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing Minecraft PE on an old world with no tall grass, and I'm not sure how to get wheat seeds. I've tried using a hoe on grass, but it doesn't work, and there are no villages on the map. How can I obtain wheat seeds in MCPE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get wheat seeds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240747/how-do-i-get-wheat-seeds)

Comment: @Banana97286 he says he has no tall grass tho so that solution wouldnt work, this is a special situation

Answer (score 2):

If your world is old and lacks the tall grass that is now required to obtain wheat seeds, what you need is [bonemeal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bonemeal). Using bonemeal on a patch of grass will produce an area of tall grass (and some flowers), which can then be cut down for some [seeds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seeds) (if you have a tool enchanted with fortune, the drop rate of seeds from tall grass is higher).

Once you have some seeds, make some farmland with a hoe and grow wheat. Once the wheat is fully grown, harvesting it will yield seeds in addition to wheat, often more than enough to replant what you harvested, allowing you to grow more and more with each harvest.

In order to obtain bonemeal, you need to put bone(s) into a single square of the crafting window. To obtain [bones](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone); you can either kill skeletons, or go [fishing](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing). Getting bones from fishing may be rare, as they are part of the 'junk' rewards, which you only get 10% of the time on an unenchanted rod.

Comment: I did my best to confirm through the [wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki) that all the mechanics I've listed work in pocket edition. They seem to, but it is hard to tell sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get seeds from 1.) Hoeing dirt or 2.) Breaking dirt.

You can also get seeds and wheat from villages.